# MongoDB query array of objects

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I have the following collection

```
{
  "collection": "user",
  "shouldUpdate": false,
  "loadOrder": 1,
  "data": [{
    "avatarUrl": "/profiles/photo.do?uid=ddd",
    "userName": "ddd",
    "firstName": "Doron",
    "lastName": "Solomon",
    "password": "password",
    "email": "x@x.com",
    "masteries": []
  }, {
    "avatarUrl": "/profiles/photo.do?uid=bbb",
    "userName": "bbb",
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Goodman",
    "password": "bWIxNzcz",
    "email": "y@y.com",
    "masteries": []
  }]
}
```

I am trying to query this coolection and return only one object from the data array but I am always getting all the collection back
I tried:

```
db.users.find({ "data.lastName": "Solomon"}).pretty()
```

also:

```
db.users.find({ data:{ $elemMatch: {lastName: "Solomon" }}}).pretty()
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is correct, but as you want only matched object from data array, then you have to mention that in **`projection`**.

```
db.users.find({ "data.lastName": "Solomon"},{"data.$": 1}).pretty()
```

**`$`**, is a positional operator in mongo. It will project only matched documents from data array `"data.$": 1`.

Comment: It works, Thank you :-)
In order for me to learn if I only want to return the firstName that matches this lastName what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to query just:

> db.users.find({ lastName: "Solomon" })